# Powershell remote to TFS not working

Tags: powershell, tfs, powershell-remoting

I am trying to get the latest for a user on a build server.  I have created a powershell script to do this and the script finishes successfully but the folder isn't updated.  If I open a powershell session and go through line by line typing them out manually it works.  But running the script does not.

```
$tf = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe '
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName server -Credential user
Invoke-Command $s -ScriptBlock{
cd c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sqlwebservice 
& $args[0] @('get ', '. ', '/r')
cd SyncService
dir
exit
} -ArgumentList ($tf) 
Pause
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you run the script as part of your build process or just run it on your local machine?

Comment: I run it on my local machine.  It updates a folder for a generic login that runs the builds.  This way I can check-in changes to an XML, run this script, and the user that runs the builds gets updated with out me having to remote to that server.

Answer (score 0):

According to your situation, if it works line by line and not work as a script. You can wait on the job to finish with a timeout (in case the command hangs) by using `-Timeout`. Take a look at below two links:

- [Powershell script works on Powershell window line-by-line, but not in script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36946662/powershell-script-works-on-powershell-window-line-by-line-but-not-in-script)
- [PowerShell start-sleep cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430615/powershell-start-sleep-cmdlet)

Comment: Awesome.  I'll check it out.  Thanks!